# Parse pdf from Django InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, django, pdf

Received a pdf file using Django rest_framework. I tried several ways to parse content from incoming file.

> curl -vX POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/documents/ -d @10_CSS\ (1).pdf --header "Content-Type: application/pdf" --header "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=10_css.pdf"

```
def create(self, request):        
    file_ = request.FILES['file'] 

    parser = PDFParser(file_)     
    document = PDFDocument(parser)
```

> PDFSyntaxError: No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?

```
def create(self, request):        
    file_ = request.FILES['file'] 

    parser = PDFParser(file_.read())     
    document = PDFDocument(parser)
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

```
def create(self, request):        
    utf8_file = codecs.EncodedFile(request.FILES['file'], "utf-8")
    with open('/tmp/whatever.pdf', 'wb+') as destination:         
        for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():              
            destination.write(chunk)                              

    file_ = open('/tmp/whatever.pdf', 'rb')                       
    parser = PDFParser(file_)                                     
    document = PDFDocument(parser)
```

> PDFSyntaxError: No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?

I tried several pdf files with the same result. And when I tried to parse a pdf file before I sent it to my application it parsed well. **How to parse a pdf file from `InMemoryUploadedFile`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using:

```
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
```

In that case your header (--header "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=10_css.pdf") is included in the file.

I suggest you use `MultiPartParser` and don't send the Content-Disposition header.

[More informations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser)